# enterprise_logging_event_changes table in the DB

Tags: magento-enterprise, database, enterprise-1.14, ee-1.14.2.0

Very general question, but is it okay to clear out the old data in this table prior to go-live? It has a bunch of old development data inside.

Pros / Cons?

Is it useful to keep around or better to just delete and start fresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine to remove.

Maintenance scripts out there will truncate it and update the auto increment back, it really depends how heavily the site has been used for testing, because that will determine how much data you're moving over from the test site.